# node-gyp compile error - The handle is invalid

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, npm, node-gyp, lwip

Installing [lwip](https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip) module (that provide image processing and manipulation without external runtime dependencies):

```
npm install lwip
```

I' receiving the following output:

```
> lwip@0.0.5 install C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\Progetti\wacomdev\node_modules\lwip
> node-gyp rebuild
C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\Progetti\wacomdev\node_modules\lwip>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\gyp", line 18, in <module> 
    sys.exit(gyp.main(sys.argv[1:]))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 526, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 502, in gyp_main
    options.circular_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\__init__.py", line 98, in Load
    generator.CalculateVariables(default_variables, params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\generator\msvs.py", line 1713, in CalculateVariables
    generator_flags.get('msvs_version', 'auto'))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 366, in SelectVisualStudioVersion
    versions = _DetectVisualStudioVersions(version_map[version], 'e' in version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 305, in _DetectVisualStudioVersions
    path = _RegistryGetValue(keys[index], 'InstallDir')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 167, in _RegistryGetValue
    text = _RegistryQuery(key, value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 149, in _RegistryQuery
    text = _RegistryQueryBase('Sysnative', key, value)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\gyp\pylib\gyp\MSVSVersion.py", line 120, in _RegistryQueryBase
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\python27_x64\lib\subprocess.py", line 701, in __init__
    errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\python27_x64\lib\subprocess.py", line 822, in _get_handles
    p2cread = _subprocess.GetStdHandle(_subprocess.STD_INPUT_HANDLE)
WindowsError: [Error 6] The handle is invalid
gypnpm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\Progetti\wacomdev\node_modules\lwip\src\lib\jpeg'
npm ERR! error rolling back  lwip@0.0.5 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\Progetti\wacomdev\node_modules\lwip\src\lib\jpeg']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Users\\Admin\\Dropbox\\Progetti\\wacomdev\\node_modules\\lwip\\src\\lib\\jpeg' }
npm ERR! lwip@0.0.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the lwip@0.0.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the lwip package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls lwip
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "lwip" "--save"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\Dropbox\Progetti\wacomdev
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.14
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm
====npm command completed with exit code 1====
```

I'm currently using:

- Windows 7 Professional 64bit
- Visual Studio Premium 2013
- Python (2.7)